# apache http client request properties access

Tags: java, spring, apache

I use apache the http client library in spring based java application. Customer needs additional logging in the special format.

The line in the log should look like this:

google.com 10.13.111.101 - - [02/Jan/2017:20:03:16 +0600] [duration: 10226195 us (10 s)] "POST /aaa/bbb.asmx HTTP/1.1" 500 342 (redir=-, SID=-) "Java1.6.0_85" bytes sent: 2108

There are couple of solutions which come to my mind, but none from below seems to be ideal:

- Use apache proxy server - this is forbidden for this application
- Use URL connection - also not viable for this application
- Use apache client logging - this provides all the information, but on the few lines, one of the solution would be to log into memory and reformat the log, but this solution fails once apache changes a log format a bit.
- Use reflection to access properties from the request/response - using reflection faces the same problem as above.
- Change the apache client code itself - also ugly approach

Solution I will probably finally use:

- I will enclose the client into my object which logs everything itself. I do not like this solution much because it doubles the functionality of the apache http client. For example if I need a duration of the request I have no chance to get it from the request/response object programatically. I would need to measure the time by myself. The same for IP address. I need additional request just to uncover the IP address just for logging purpose :-(

What would be nice to have:

- Use some java proxy framework which I simply add to the spring ecosystem and it gives me all the info of outgoing/incoming http requests/responses and I can simply log information I need. Is there any of such thing?

Or do you have any other ideas how to deal with it?

Comment: I had a quick look at the http client source and it could be possible to extend the appropiate classes with your custom solution. If its possible, it could be an elegant solution.

Comment: thanks for effort, finally I think I have found the solution: there exist a HttpRequestInterceptor and a HttpResponseInterceptor which can be plugged into the HttpClient and seem to do their job. Once I finish the implementation I will provide better overview for others.